# SQL query / procedure to convert hierarchy into nested set

Tags: mysql, sql, data-structures, nested

I've a lot of classic (mysql) tables with id and parent_id which I need to convert into n [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). For each row I need to calculate depth (which can vary) and left / right node.

Is it possible to do it with mySQL query or stored procedure?

Edit: depth can vary, so nested joins aren't best solution.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html

Comment: Yes, thank you, actually EdgeListToNestedSet (http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html#nested_set_model) works like a charm. You can post it as a response if you mind to score few points :)

Comment: It's OK, I'm pacing myself :-)